# Align multiple items based on the row location

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using 2 internal company related components `Row` and `Column` which I can't change but they both take in `style` property thus could pass in any css styling.

Note that I have to use these components for other purposes.

This is currently how it looks which is incorrect.

[image]

Can see 2 issues.

1. Due to product subtile on the first, the second one mis aligned.
2. Due to more text on the description on the second, again mis aligned.

I am looking to achieve this.

[image]

Is there a way to do this. Was attempting with flex box but due to the way the divs are nested, struggling with it.

It would work if I switch it around and create by row.

Meaning don't create a column one short like this.

[image]

But go for row by row like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I can't do this due to accessibility. The screen reader should read column by column. But ends up reading row by row if I do this.

Example: `Product Title 1` `Product Title 2` and then coming back to `Cost $1000` switching between the 2 products which is incorrect.

Thus I wish to stick with creating 1 column at a time as what I have now but how can I achieve the desired row alignment? Please help. Thanks.

My code.

This is the main Row for both items.

```
<Row style={'I can pass styling here'}> 
    {products}
</Row>
```

This is where I am looping and creating column by column for the products.

```
  const products = productsList.slice(0, 3) // screenshot above shows 2 but can go up to 3
    .map((p, index) => (
      <Column style={'I can pass styling here'}>

       {/* The image, title and subtitle all come from here */}
        <SelectedProduct/>

        {/* price description section*/}
        {price(p, index)}

        {/* button and links here. 
            These are not having alignment issues. Fixing subtitle and description alignments should take care of this 
        */}
        {links(p)}

      </Column>
    ));
```

Condensed SelectedProduct component.

```
const SelectedProduct = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.product}>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        <div>
          <Link to={redirectTo}>
            <Art src={url} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <TrackedRemoveButton type="button"/>
      </div>

      <Typography>
        {title}
      </Typography>

      <Typography>
        {subtitle}
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};
```

styling in SelectedProduct

```
.product {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Condensed price component.

```
  const price = (p) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography>
            <span
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: p.content,
                }}
            />
        </Typography>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I would suggest `min-height` on each element in the column and some sort of function that reacts to the height of the tallest description (because that seems like the information that can vary the most), and applies it to each column dynamically.

Comment: @J.Titus Do you mean I will check for max height between the 3 SelectedProduct components created and store the max value in useState. And then use that in style as min value. And then also do the same with a second state for price?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: @J.Titus Think I am leaning towards this idea. Wondering if using useRefs might be a better option to track the height of the component. Thanks.

Comment: What about if you gave your <SelectProduct/> `flex-grow: 1`, and then did the same with the subtitle? That way the Product should grow to occupy max space, and your subtitle will occupy max space within that?

Comment: @JohnDetlefs But how would you target since the divs are nested. Would you be able to show an example for the above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a surprisingly difficult problem. Here is my solution: https://codepen.io/dlwalsh/pen/gOdayNQ

It uses flexbox with column direction. The important bits are:

1. The parent declaration `align-items: stretch` so that each item extends to the full height.
2. The button declaration `margin-top: auto` so that it (and everything beneath it) anchors to the bottom.

It works, but it relies on everything else having a fixed height. i.e.

- The title and subtitle are always one line
- A blank subtitle inserted when missing
- There are always exactly two product links

Comment: The tile is possible to be up to 3 lines unfortunately. The product link assumption is correct.